# Unable to login to TFS account

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

My account on TFS used to work perfectly. Now it is throwing error message like this

[image]

I am giving my credentials correctly. Then I contacted my adminstrator, he said that I dont have any restriction on TFS account. Then I found some online solutions like

- Clearing cache of all the browsers in P.C.
- Resetting of my previous password.
- Clearing cache of visual studio Asp.Net folder in C drive.
- Clearing cache of Team Foundation Folder in C drive.
- Removing TFS account from control panel >> user account.
- Unchecking of all checkboxes in LAN settings in Internet Explorer.

I did all of them but none of them worked.

Please help!!!

Comment: Which version of TFS are you trying to connect? Which version of VS/Team Explorer are you using? Are you able to access the TFS from Web Access with the same credential you  use in VS/Team Explorer?

Comment: I think it is 6.0... yes i m able login to microsoft visual studio web page using the same credentials. I am using visual studio 2010 and 2015... it was working on both of them

Comment: TFS 6.0? Where did you get this version? Could you double check?

Comment: Are you using the hosted Visual Studio Team Service or on-premise TFS?